# How to make LDAP requests (Port 389) over AnyConnect 3.1 on OSX 10.11.6?

Tags: windows, osx-el-capitan, ldap, cisco-vpn-client

It's my understanding that OSX doesn't like to allow VPN port traffic on ports under 1000.
How can we get LDAP requests to work for us?

Error:

```
ldap client error { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND server.domain.local server.domain.local:389]
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'server.domain.local',
  host: 'server.domain.local',
  port: 389 }
```

* server name changed to protect the innocent

Any chance this is because OSX can't resolve the windows host name?

Comment: LDAP is not an issue on Windows clients.

Answer (score -2):

Resolve the server name to its IP and use that rather than the network name.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to determine the reason OS X wasn't able to lookup the ip address of the client?  Seems like a pretty poor work around if you have to always use the ip address instead of the host name.

Comment: Agreed. A better answer is definitely preferred.

Comment: However, installing Bonjour on the Windows hosts is not an option.

Comment: We're going to test the answer here https://superuser.com/a/416102 and, if it works, add another answer.

Comment: Your question makes no mention of Windows being used.  Just noticed the vague comment about Windows, your question, makes no mention of it though.

Comment: Correct. My omission has been resolved.